What would the climates/biomes on my fantasy continent be?
I've roughly marked out where I think a desert might naturally form according to the mountains, and plotted the rivers in a way that I think makes sense, but what other climates might I expect on this continent?
It's roughly the same size as Australia, in an Earth-like world in around the same position on the planet that Australia is/same positioning to the equator. There are no other continents nearby.
I imagine there would be a desert, similar to the Nullabor plains, tropical areas around the coast lines, and maybe some temperate forests around the bottom? This is a rough map, so if it's not accurate in some way I'm willing to make changes to it.


Sorry, no-one can give you an answer without first seeing the rest of your world.
The problem is there's no details about the other continents/major land masses. On Earth climate is not just driven by latitude and wind speed direction. In particular it's driven by ocean currents and their interaction with the surrounding land masses.  For example Google ocean currents in the Atlantic and their effect on regional climates. As an example? Thanks to the Gulf Stream/Atlantic drift the climate in the UK is a lot warmer than the equivalent latitude in Canada. Shift/pivot South America and Africa further north and Australia immediately gets greater exposure to the southern west wind drift current and becomes colder and wetter (at least the southern half) as a result.
You see the problem? Basically land masses act like shields that deflect cold and warm ocean currents in directions they wouldn't go if the land masses weren't there! So long story short you need to plot out the rough distribution of ALL the continents on your world before someone can give you a fairly reliable answer using Earth's currents and climate as a template.
P.S. Don't bother with details! Just draw a globe with rough outlines of the continents and large islands and include your continent in the desired latitude/longitude.
It's a lovely map BTW. Well done!

I assumed OPs continent is surrounded by open ocean on all sides. If so, the map is fairly realistic, as long as the central dry plains are on a sufficient elevation.
Im not sure why the south-east archipelago is so poorly forested, but this can easily be caused by poor soil, rather than climate issues.

As I stated. The problem isn't Ops continent. It's the position of ALL the other continents/large islands etc in OPs world. IF OPs is the only  continent on his/her world? No problem. At the given latitude? It will be creatively cool, well watered & green with few (if any) desert regions simply because there are no other major land masses to disrupt the  circulation of the cold/cool currents circulating around those latitudes in the southern hemisphere. If it's NOT the only continent/large island etc in the southern hemisphere? Those currents WILL be disrupted/alter course & change its climate

thank you @Mon! I did intend for the continent to not have any close by neighbours, and for it to be the only land within miles and miles. If there is another continent, it's on the other side of the planet. Not sure if that changes anything

@bruithel. No probs. I suggest you draw a quick globe with both continents on it.  Assuming your world is in most respect otherwise more or less identicle to Earth?  you then look at a map showing how the  worlds great currents currently flow around the real continents you can probably 'guesstimate' for yourself how they would work on your world.
